# Origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: visualforce, javascript, callout, xml, cors

I understand there are lots of questions and answers related to CORS policy, but here I wanted to make sure if I'm understanding it right and solving it the right way.

I have a visualforce page that is supposed to call an external system through XML HTTP Request, the VF page uses XMLHttpRequest javascript to do the request as can be seen in the below code snippet;

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">

    <script>
       function soap() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://client-url-that-gives-the-wsdl', true)
    // build SOAP request
    var sr =
        '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:cbs-messagegatewaysoap:2015-01-01">' +
        '<soapenv:Header/>' +
        '<soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
            '<urn:MGRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +
                '<urn:Message GroupId="2b668cb9-038e-413d-b9c2-dfbc38c4104f" Id="45397ed8-dbd7-4b61-aa0d-b497e88a9548" TimeStamp="2017-04-11T14:42:47.662197+01:00" Idempotence="unique"' + 'xmlns="urn:cbs-messagegatewaysoap:2015-01-01">' +
                    '<urn:Credential Domain="" Id="****" Password="*****' +
                '</urn:Message>' +
                '<urn:Product ServiceId="CB" Id="CB_NAE_Product" Version="" xmlns="urn:cbs-messagegatewaysoap:2015-01-01">' +
                    '<cb:CB_NAE_ProductInput xmlns:cb="urn:crif-creditbureau:v1">' +
                        '<cb:Subject SubjectRefDate="2019-11-22">' +
                            '<cb:Individual DebtorGroupCodeInd="9700" Gender="L" MarriageStatus="1" EducationalStatusCode="01">' +
                                '<cb:IndividualName NameAsId="xx" FullName="xx" MothersName="" />' +
                                '<cb:BirthData BirthDate="1982-01-01" BirthPlace="xx" />' +
                                '<cb:Address Address="xx" SubDistrict="xx" District="xxxxx" City="0102" PostalCode="11112" Country="ID"/>' +
                                '<cb:IdentificationCode IdentityType="1" IdentityNumber="xxxxx" />' +
                                '<cb:ID NPWP="" />' +
                                '<cb:Contact PhoneNumber="" CellphoneNumber="xxx" EmailAddress="" />' +
                                '<cb:EmploymentData JobCode="" Workplace="" CodeOfBusiness="" WorkplaceAddress="" />' +
                            '</cb:Individual>' +
                        '</cb:Subject>' +
                        '<cb:Application ContractCategoryCode="F01" ContractTypeCode="10" ContractPhase="RQ" ContractRequestDate="2019-11-22" Currency="IDR">' +
                            '<cb:Credit ApplicationAmount="12000000" DueDate="2040-03-04" OriginalAgreementNumber="24" OriginalAgreementDate="2019-09-08" />' +
                        '</cb:Application>' +
                        '<cb:Link Role="B" />' +
                        '<cb:ApplicationCodes ProviderContractNo="" ProviderApplicationNo="A2A_APP001" CBContractCode=""/>' +
                        '<cb:Purpose PurposeCode="12" />' +
                    '</cb:CB_NAE_ProductInput>' +
                '</urn:Product>' +
            '</urn:MGRequest>' +
        '</soapenv:Body>' +
        '</soapenv:Envelope>'
        
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                // alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
            }
        }
    }
    // Send the POST request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    xmlhttp.send(sr);

    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="XML Http Request, Click on the button..."> 
            <!-- Command button to create Remote Site Setting -->
            <apex:commandButton value="Send" onclick="soap();return false;"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And I get this error when clicking the button

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at <host url> from origin 'https://mycompany--c.visualforce.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

--> I checked some articles to add `setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` and the issue still there.

--> I added a remote setting with my `https://*.host-url.com` and the issue still there

other articles say, this is really from the server side CORS policy, so I contacted the API provider and they say "no IP whitelisting" the client must check again the configuration, and at this point, I really appreciate if someone could give me some insight what should I do next in order to get this thing working.

Comment: The server sets CORS headers. Good primer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS . If the server does not support CORS, you have to make calls through a proxy (that you have to implement) or make calls from a server-side component. The latter is a viable strategy for VF pages. It's unclear why you're making this call from the client but if there isn't a strong rationale for that, move the call to a custom controller for VF page.

Comment: @identigral your advice does make sense, I don't have a valid reason to make the call from the client as it was for testing only, moving it to the server-side would be a good way to go. thanks